# php how to get each number in this json tree?

Tags: php, json

```
{
    "value": {
        "num": [
            [
                [
                    12, // $num1
                    34  // $val1
                ],
                [
                    15, // $num2
                    47  // $val2
                ],
                [
                    7,  // $num3
                    86  // $val3
                ],
                [
                    9,  // $val4
                    101  // $val4
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I have already use json decode. How to get each value in this json tree? I only can get `$num1` & `$val1`, but I still want to get the rests. Thanks.

```
foreach ($data['value']['num'] as $data) 
  $num1= $data[0][0];
 $val1= $data[0][1];
```

Comment: Why $data['value']['num'] got an array with a single value and not directly the array with $nums and $vals?

Comment: You need to iterate over the right array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($data['value']['num'][0] as $data) {
  $num[]= $data[0];
  $val[]= $data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $result) {
  $num[]= $result['num'];
  $val[]= $result['value'];
}
```

can u try this